# Validate a raising of event

Tags: c#, events

I try to validate a raising of event:

I have a Device which return me some message after I send it a command.

I have an event which is raise when I got new message on my serial port.

I recover this event and I want to do a validation of this raising before sending an other command to my Device.

```
Public Constructor()
{
 ModuleProtocole.MessageReceive += SendValidate;
}

SendValidate()
{
//maybe something to write here?
}

SendNewMessage()
{
 ModuleProtocole.SendMessage ("Version");
 // if SendValidate() is call because of event go to next line
 ModuleProtocole.SendMessage ("Value1");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question, and to give the simplest possible answer.

```
private bool? _hasEventBeenRaised;

private void SendValidate()
{
   _hasEventBeenRaised = true;
}

private void SendNewMessage()
{
   if(_hasEventBeenRaised == false)
   {
      Console.WriteLine("No event received");
      return;
   }
   
   _hasEventBeenRaised = false;

   // send message
    
}
```

<sub>***Note** : This disregaurds any other issue, additionally if the event is raised on another thread, you will want to use `lock` to ensure there is no threading issues.*</sub>

An overly cautious lock approach

```
private bool? _hasEventBeenRaised;
private object _sync = new object();

private void SendValidate()
{
   lock(_sync)
   {
      _hasEventBeenRaised = true;
   }
}

private void SendNewMessage()
{
    lock(_sync)
    {
       if(_hasEventBeenRaised == false)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("No event received");
           return;
       }
   
       _hasEventBeenRaised = false;

       // send message
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the SendValidate function (which is a called when the device responds to the 1st message) to do the sending of the second message?

But ideally i'd do it with some signals, so basically i'd create a send message, which blocks - waits for a signal (initially should be free), then locks the signal (semaphore) and then sends the message. The message callback event then should free the signal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netcore-3.1

```
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1, 1); // 1 available call, max. 1 concurrent calls

SendMessage()
{
  this.semaphore.WaitOne();
  // NOTE: add send message here
}

MessageReceived()
{
  this.semaphore.Release(1);
}
```