# WPF, C#, how to control program sequence when communicating with machine through COM port

Tags: c#, wpf, automation, serial-port

I have a project which needs to use WPF, C# to communicate and control a machine through COM port.

Program needs to control machine in below operation:

- Program sends "command 1" to machine, then wait and validate reply from machine through COM port.
- Once program verified correct reply from machine for command 1, program will send "command 2" to machine, then wait and validate reply again.

This operation repeats until all commands are executed.

I have done the COM port communication using SerialPort, DataReceived with SerialDataReceivedEventHandler. Testing using a button click event to send 1 command to machine, it works fine.

I would like to ask how to validate reply from machine for "command 1", after validation done, auto send next command to machine, validate reply and continue for a list of commands ?

Below is the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
SerialPort serial = new SerialPort();
string recieved_data;  // get reply from machine through COM port

private void Connect_Comms(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
serial.DataReceived += new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(Recieve);
}

private delegate void UpdateUiTextDelegate(string text);
private void Recieve(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
        recieved_data = serial.ReadExisting();         
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Send, new UpdateUiTextDelegate(updateUI), recieved_data);
}

private void updateUI(string text)
{  /* update GUI */ }
 
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        serial.Write("command 1");
        // -> how to check reply 1 (recieved_data) before send command 2 ???

        serial.Write("command 2");
        // -> how to check reply 2 (recieved_data) before send command 3 ???

        serial.Write("command 3");
}
}
```

Comment: This seems like a surprisingly similar question (+ extension) to this quertion asked a few minutes ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048911/c-sharp-validate-a-raising-of-event If you guys are at the same work / school, I would consider talking to each other and working on this together

Comment: @TheGeneral: we are not the same work/school, but looks like our questions are somehow similar in the point that how to control machine through COM with sending a command, then validate reply before sending next command. I would like to know what is the best way to achieve this. Thanks.